# Как сделать, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку JButton в JTable добавлялся ArrayList?

Tags: applet, java, swing

Здравствуйте.

Такая проблема: у меня две Frame - на первой находится таблица JTable, a на второй несколько JTextField (эти текстфилды я складываю в один ArrayList) и одна JButton. Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку JButton в JTable добавлялся мой ArrayList?

Comment: Смотря что за Frame - оригинальный JFrame или еще какой, или класс-наследник. Уточните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @hangov3r, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Оба окна создаю оригинальным Jframe. Второе окно открывается при нажатии на кнопку.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, следует начать с того, что просто взять и добавить `ArrayList` или любую другую коллекцию нельзя, не то что нельзя, в этом попросту нету необходимости. Для начала посмотрите в сторону такого архитектурного подхода `MVC(Model View Controller)`. В данной ситуации у Вас `jTable` (графический компонент) будет представлять собой `View`, ну а модель, соответственно, будет ту, которую Вы зададите. Модель обычно интерфейс, который в свою очередь имеет обычно стандартную реализацию для примера. Соответственно Вам нужно поработать с моделью. Для начала посмотрите пример `DefaultTreeModel`. Почитайте про данный подход, по началу будет казаться странным, а потом поймете, что действительно все логично.